# How can I go to Documents folder in Mac with Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line

I am following a Java tutorial that I should first browse to the JAR file that I have saved in Documents folder on my Mac..How do we go there by terminal commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to write down in the console `cd /Users/username/Documents/` when username is your user, then you can write `ls` to show a list of files in that folder.

Answer (score 7):

You can type `cd /Users/yourusername/Documents` to go to your documents folder. `cd` is the terminal command to change the directory you're working in.

You can also type `cd ~/Documents` (~ is short for your home directory).

Finally, if you go to your home folder in the Finder, you can drag Documents onto the terminal window, and it will show the path to it. This is useful if you ever have a file or folder that you want to learn the path to.

Answer (score 3):

After macOS Catalina (10.15), SIP (macOS sandbox) prevents the general folder access from the Terminal.
See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395631/allow-all-applications-to-access-desktop-documents-and-downloads-in-catalina

Comment: I get `operation not permitted` when trying to access `downloads` in terminal on Monterey.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need to do to run the jar file:

```
java -jar ~/Documents/jar
```

This is really what you want to do, as this runs the file you've created and the

```
cd ~/Documents/
```

command only sets the terminal to work in the Documents directory (i.e., folder), but little else.